# Get a child of a parent using pointer

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to get a child when I have his parent. 
I created a child (comment) , a parent (post) and a pointer from the child to the parent-

```
    // Create the post
    ParseObject myPost = new ParseObject("Post");
    myPost.put("title", "I'm Hungry");
    myPost.put("content", "Where should we go for lunch?");


    // Create the comment
    ParseObject myComment = new ParseObject("Comment");
    myComment.put("content", "Let's do Sushirrito.");

    // Add a relation between the Post and Comment
    myComment.put("parent", myPost);

    // This will save both myPost and myComment
    myComment.saveInBackground();
```

My query:

```
String t="";
ParseObject c;

 ParseQuery<ParseObject> query =
      ParseQuery.getQuery("Comment");
       query.whereEqualTo("parent",myPost );   
       query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> list,com.parse.ParseException e) {
              if (e == null) {
                c= list.get(0);
                t= c.getString("content");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  t , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                                 
                } else {
                    Log.d("NY", "Model.getStudentById Error: " + e.getMessage());
                    }

                }
      });
```

but I did not get the comment.
I tried also to put  query.include("parent"); but it did not work.

what should I do??
thanks

Comment: In your code, you never save `myPost`. Can you confirm (via Parse Dashboard) that your "Post" object is actually being created?

Comment: ParseObject myPost = new ParseObject("Post"); myPost.put("title", "I'm Hungry"); myPost.put("content", "Where should we go for lunch?"); - this code save the object and create the table in the parse. I checked it in my parse and see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can figure out is that you might be trying to retrieve the `myPost` object from another method before it's actually been saved to Parse.

When I copied your code into a test project, I couldn't get it to work. Here's an updated version that **does** work.

***Note:*** *I'm chaining the operations so that I'm sure (well, as sure as I can be... you still need good error/exception handling) that the previous operation completed before performing the next.*

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Parse.initialize(this, "<value>", "<value>");
    createPost();
}

private void createPost() {
    ParseObject myPost = new ParseObject("Post");
    myPost.put("title", "I'm Hungry");
    myPost.put("content", "Where should we go for lunch?");

    mPost = myPost;

    ParseObject myComment = new ParseObject("Comment");
    myComment.put("content", "Let's do Sushirrito.");

    myComment.put("parent", myPost);

    myComment.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Comment");
            query.whereEqualTo("parent", mPost);
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> list, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        ParseObject c = list.get(0);
                        String t = c.getString("content");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Log.d("NY", "Model.getStudentById Error: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The code above shows my "Hello World" Activity and then posts a Toast that says "Let's do Sushirrito."